# Recursive combinations with subsets in Elixir

Tags: recursion, combinatorics, elixir

```
defmodule Combination do
  def combine([]) do
    []
  end

  def combine([head | tail]) do
    tail_combinations = combine(tail)
    merged_combinations = Enum.map(
      [[]] ++ tail_combinations,
      fn c -> c ++ [head] end
    )
    tail_combinations ++ merged_combinations
  end
end
```

This Elixir function produces all combinations of all subsets (including the complete one) of the items in the given list. For an empty list, it returns an empty list.

Examples:

```
> Combination.combine([])
[]
> Combination.combine(["a"])
[["a"]]
> Combination.combine(["a", "b"])
[["b"], ["a"], ["b", "a"]]
> Combination.combine(["a", "b", "c"])
[["c"], ["b"], ["c", "b"], ["a"], ["c", "a"], ["b", "a"], ["c", "b", "a"]]
```

I like that there is no duplication happening that would require using a `MapSet` or a conditional before adding the combination to the output list. I feel wrong about:

- The `combine` call on the empty tail in the last iteration. Can I get rid of it?
- The complex `Enum.map` call. Can I replace the closure with a more straightforward private module function?